# Is it possible to log setdebug(true) messages in Java Mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use Java Mail to send email to another user. And with `session.setDebug(true);`,it logs the message on the console in this form (for e.g):

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a129sm15758138pfa.152 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 25

EHLO DESKTOP-QRDQAL4
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [211.24.105.229]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
```

So it keeps all the messages going on here and there.I also have another logger to keep track of any info or error like this:

```
TerminalLogger.printMsg("Email sent successful.....etc");
```

Now I would like to log the `set.debug` messages into my log file like:

```
TerminalLogger.printMsg(session.setDebug(true));
```

But obviously, it's a void method and doesn't pass in string value. Is there a way I could fit debug messages into my log?

Comment: `TerminalLogger.printMsg(session.setDebug(true));` suppose this actually worked: what would you expect it to do? I mean, what would your expected outcome be?

Comment: Anyway, `Session` has a [`setDebugOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Session.html#setDebugOut-java.io.PrintStream-) method that accepts a `PrintStream`, which may get you started.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It says java.lang.string cannot be applied to (void)

Comment: Expected outcome would be what the debug message shown above,just that those messages are saved in a log file.

Comment: It looks like you are using some logging framework that redirects standard out to the mentioned log file. This might be for example the logging of the application container or similar.

Comment: JavaMail will also log using java.util.logging, if you have a way to direct those log messages to your log file.